# cakephp link without url encoding

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP 2.2.3

I have something like this:

```
$this->Html->link('here',
      array(
        'controller' => 'biz',
        'action' => 'search',
        'range' => '1+3'),
      array('escape' => false));
```

When I click on this link the url will be encoded like this:

```
/biz/search/range:1%2B3
```

But I need

```
/biz/search/range:1+3
```

Is there any way to switch off url encoding or should I change my controller which parses the named parameter??

Comment: you can decode the parameter in the corresponding controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
    $this->Html->link('here',
      array(
        'controller' => 'biz',
        'action' => 'search',
        'range' => '1\+3'),
      array('escape' => '\'));
```

Comment: You can't do it in the controller. I tested the code above and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply can you try this

```
//search.ctp
echo $this->Html->link('here', '/biz/search/range:1+3');
```

Receive this in controller

```
 //BizController.php
 public function search() {
    var_dump($this->request->params['named']);
    // do something     
 }
```

Comment: Where as this works, it fits better with the CakePHP framework to use that array syntax